# Как setTextColor сделать static?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно метод из одного `AppCompatActivity` задействовать в другом `AppCompatActivity` в методе есть `setTextColor` в котором я использую `ContextCompat.getColor`, чтобы всё заработало нужно чтобы `context` находился в методе `static`, но это делать нельзя , получаю такую ошибку `error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`. Как сделать чтобы в методе `static`, `setTextColorё` заработал?

Метод в котором ругается на `context`-`this`

```
    public static void changeAttractionText() {
        attractionText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_2));
        rinkText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_0));
        newsText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_0));
        profileText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_0));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так не работает что-ли:

```
public static void changeAttractionText(Context context) {
    attractionText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_2));
    rinkText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_0));
    newsText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_0));
    profileText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_0));
}
```

Comment: А что тогда писать в скобках при вызове changeAttractionText()?

Comment: ну если вызываете из активити, можете написать "this", а так всегда можно написать "getApplicationContext()"

Comment: Спасибо, заработало